# use two external hard drive as one

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I am planning to purchase a second external hard drive and I am trying to figure out a minimalist setting to use two external drives at the same time (I don’t want to plug two drives into my computer, so ruled out that solution). In addition, I also have a laptop drive at spare. So if there is a way I can use it with my existing external drive, I don’t even need to buy a new drive.

Here is what I am thinking:

1. Using an external drive docking station. The problem is I need to break my current external drive casing and pull out the drive inside. I am not sure if that internal piece would require some extra circuits, and if it is of standard size (2.5” or 3.5”)
2. Somehow connect two external drives in serial, so I only need to plug in one drive into my computer to access them both. A slight disturbance is power supply. Not sure if the "main" drive can provide enough current to the secondary drive.

The first way is more economically sound, since I have a spare laptop drive. The second way sounds more robust. But I don’t know exactly whether either of them work.

I understand I can just buy an enclosure for the laptop drive and use it as an external. But my question is how can I use two external drives as I am just using one (with a single connecting cable to my computer).

Comment: How else are you going to connect two external drives to your laptop, if you don't plug them in, I don't understand what you are trying achieve.  USB devices you want to use cannot be connected in serial.

Comment: I am trying to use only 1 cable for two hard drives. Will the usb hud provide enough voltage to power an external drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is important, you don't want to be doing anything "non-standard".

I would say you have two safe solutions that come to mind:

1. Buy a larger external drive.
2. Buy an enclosure that supports multiple drives and configurations and install the drives in that.  You may need to buy a 2.5" to 3.5" adapter.  And depending on the enclosure purchased, the drives may be seen as a single drive by the operating system or separate drives using a single connection.

Note, it's quite possible any "dual" drive solution will likely require separate power whereas a single laptop hard drive connected externally can have power supplied by the computer's USB port.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

1. Get a little passive USB hub.
2. Plug both the drives into the Hub.
3. Put a piece of packing foam on either side of the hub and sandwich it between the drives.
4. Wrap it with duct tape and you have one unit with one cable to connect to your computer.

Comment: Hilarious suggestion, good idea!

Comment: Wrapping hard drives with foam & duct tape sounds pretty bad for heat buildup... might as well splurge on a cardboard box with air space around the drives, even a usb fan & vent holes, similar to this image https://cdn.instructables.com/FTM/QIJF/HDOW9Y7R/FTMQIJFHDOW9Y7R.MEDIUM.jpg?width=614

Answer (score 1):

I would use a network drive with two bays. You don't say if your host is a laptop or a desktop, or how it is networked (Ethernet or WiFi).

Modern NAS enclosures have one or two USB connectors, so you can plug your existing drive into it without dismantling. Depending on the network configuration, you would plug the NAS into either your router, Ethernet switch, or the host machine (with possibly a crossed LAN cable).

The second bay gives the flexibility of adding a further drive, either as additional storage, or as a RAID duplicate.

Make sure that the NAS handles the size of your current and additional external drives: many are still limited to 2TB.

Comment: Thank you! very useful for network drive configuration! However, you have a good point on the NAS size limit, and I look it up, quite expensive. But very nice to have this solution in mind!!