# How Can I Convert a 2.5" Hard Disk To a Portable External Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, external-hard-drive, portable-harddrive

I just removed the old hard drives from my laptop. I want to make my own External hard drives disk. How can I do it ?
[image]

What do I look for to find a disk enclosure compatible with my external hard disk?

Comment: Welcome to Super User Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange communities are different than other sites. Please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to see how this site works. Also review the Help Center sections on [topics to ask here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [questions to avoid](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), and [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). I can't see the materials you are referring to because I don't have an account there. Can you please refer to them by product name and number instead.

Comment: The store link seems non essential and just throws us a log in page - so I've removed it.

Comment: Is this Q Spam? Noticed the answer had an attempted edit by OP to add the store link again - just the link, no context or description

Comment: Duplicate of [use two external hard drive as one](https://superuser.com/questions/845061/use-two-external-hard-drive-as-one) ?

Answer (score 2):

You simply buy a 2.5" USB enclosure, put the disks in, reformat them if required and you have an external USB drive.

The brand of drive is unimportant, but there might be some issues if the drive is > 2tb depending on the enclosure and OS.  Also, the drive will need to be a SATA drive [ which almost all non-ancient drives are ]

Comment: *Some* laptops may have additional 'shims' on top of standard sata which would need to be removed. But yeah, any standard 2.5 inch sata enclosure would work, and they're essentially commodity items at this point. I'd go for USB 3 if I could, but USB 2 would work just as well. If its many drives, consider a dock instead.